# Nginx request process time header?

Tags: nginx, response-time

I'm trying to append a header inside nginx that will say something like 'X-Time: 0.06 seconds' which basically will be the time since nginx connected with the client and nginx responded to the client.

Thanks.

Comment: To what purpose? Why does this response time have to be sent to the client via HTTP headers?

Comment: I can see this being very useful for debugging.

Comment: What I meant was: what was the end goal, because response processing time could be had from the logs. Why send it in a header to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_time

> **$request_time**
>   request processing time in seconds with a milliseconds
>   resolution (1.3.9, 1.2.6); time elapsed since the first bytes were
>   read from the client

Since versions 1.3.9 and 1.2.6 in **common variables**.
Before: only in ngx_http_log_module.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the short answer is you cannot. Nginx don't understand the `$request_time` variable if you use something like this:

```
add_header  X-Time '$request_time';
```

Comment: I just checked today and that line works in current nginx :)